# Why Sachakan magicians communicate in Kyralian?

Tags: trudi-canavan, black-magician

In the Trudi Canavan's *Black Magician Trilogy* when Akkarin and Sonea travel to Sachaka they were able to eavesdrop on Sachakan mages who spoke Kyralian with Sachakan accent.

Why on Earth Sachakans would speak Kyralian at home?!

Comment: Telepathy is about the sending of thoughts perhaps? I know of no in universe explanation.